# Google Maps marker grouping

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to achieve the following thing: Have different types of markers on my map for example, schools, libraries, bus stops and I want to be able to show/hide each group of markers.

I have been searching google for a while but nothing came up :/

Any ideas how this can be achieved ?

Comment: I never did something like that (showing/hiding markers), so all I can is post a link to an example http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_categories.htm

Comment: Beaches code works with this fix: position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are various ways to tackle this, but let me show you one approach.

First, let's start with an array of locations (borrowed from the [Google Maps API Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?csw=1#ComplexIcons)):

```
var beaches = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 2]
];
```

This is actually an array of arrays. It represents 5 Australian beaches, and we have the name, latitude, longitude and category. The category in this case is just a number for the sake of simplicity.

Then it is important that we keep a reference of the markers that we create. To do this, we can use a `markers` array where we store each new marker, and we can also augment each marker object with its category id:

```
var markers = [];

var i, newMarker;

for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
  newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
    map: map,
    title: beaches[i][0]
  });     

  newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];     
  newMarker.setVisible(false);

  markers.push(newMarker);
}
```

Finally, when we need to show the markers, we can simply iterate over the `markers` array, and call the `setVisible()` method according to what category we would like to show.

You may want to check out the following complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Categories</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <input type="button" value="Show Group 1" onclick="displayMarkers(1);">
   <input type="button" value="Show Group 2" onclick="displayMarkers(2);">

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var beaches = [
     ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
     ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1],
     ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2],
     ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2],
     ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 2]
   ];

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   var markers = [];

   var i, newMarker;

   for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
     newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
       map: map,
       title: beaches[i][0]
     });

     newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];
     newMarker.setVisible(false);

     markers.push(newMarker);
   }

   function displayMarkers(category) {
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       if (markers[i].category === category) {
         markers[i].setVisible(true);
       }
       else {
         markers[i].setVisible(false);
       }
     }
   }

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot from the above example, after clicking on the "Show Group 2" button:

[image: Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Categories]

Comment: nice tutorial ! thanks ! 
but there is a hole in your displayMarkers function :) if we use the function to show/hide we have to check if the marker is already hidden/shown in order to set it/hide it ;) 
 for (var i = 0; i < allmarkers.length; i++) {
               if (allmarkers[i].type == type) {
                   if (allmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
                       allmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                      
                   } else {
                       allmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                    
                   }
               }
           }

Comment: @Aviatrix: My approach in the example was to hide all the markers that do not match the category argument. This happened in the `else { markers[i].setVisible(false); }` part. This means that sometimes `setVisible(false)` is called for markers that are already hidden. I assume that the Maps API checks the marker's state internally. That is why I wasn't checking the visibility with `getVisible()`... Obviously, your approach is equally good.

Comment: fixed typos in the posted code ([working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_toggleCategories.html))

Answer (score 2):

You basically just need to store references to Marker objects in an array, set their type (school, bus stop, etc.) and then on some event loop through and hide/show as appropriate:

```
var markers = [];

// create Marker

marker.locType = 'school'; //as appropriate

function hideMarkersOfType(type) {
    var i = markers.length;
    while(i--) {
        if (markers[i].locType == type) {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// similar function showMarkersOfType() calling markers[i].setVisible(true);
```

That should be a good start anyway.

Comment: except it would be better to use `markers.setMap(null);` this way the map performs better.