# Grouping lines and other elements in Google Maps (JavaScript V3 API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google Maps, so I have most likely missed something very basic. I want to group several lines, way points, locations .. logically together, so that I can switch them on / off at once. I thought this is a layer or overlay, but I am still confused about the difference.

On Playground I found the [traffic overlay example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#traffic_overlay) which is basically doing what I want to do. But what kind of overlay is right for me?  And how will draw the line to a particular overlay?

A similar question [Google Maps marker grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219437/google-maps-marker-grouping) is doing this by categories on the marker and more or less iterating through them to switch 
them on/off - is there no easier way?

I could, of course, keep all elements (lines, markers) of a group in an array and this array would represent my logical group. Is this the right way?

```
var path = waypointsToLatLngPath(myWaypoints); // generate path from waypoint
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1
});
line.setMap(map);
```

Comment: On http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html they keep the overlay elements in an array and set / unset (null) the corresponding map in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [Google Maps API v3: How to remove all markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers) and in my comment above, with V3 the right approach seems to be to keep arrays of the overlay elements and remove them by setting map to null.

I have written a little JS "class" for wrapping these aspects, so I can easily switch on/off all overlays. In V2 there was [map.clearOverlays()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544739/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-remove-all-markers), but this seems to be gone.