# "markers not defined" within toggle function (GMaps API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying for the "google maps marker grouping" tutorial:

[Google Maps marker grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219437/google-maps-marker-grouping/3219580#3219580)

In order to make the markers visible an invisible I use the following function:

```
function displayMarkers(category) {
  var i;

 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   if (markers[i].category == category) {
     if (markers[i].getVisible()) {
          markers[i].setVisible(false); }

    else { markers[i].setVisible(true); } } }
```

Here, I always get the error: markers is not defined.

Its a bit like if the markers are not visible within the function. However, if the function would be wrong there would be any remark in the discussion about the tutorial. 
So why is this error?
Tanks a lot!

Comment: Please show how `markers` is defined. Maybe your definition fails, or `markers` doesn't exist yet (asynchronous definition), or `markers` is out of the scope in `displayMarkers()`.

Comment: That tutorial didn't work as written for me, but the problem wasn't "markers not defined". [Fixed version](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_toggleCategories.html) - [Version with your displayMarkers function](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_toggleCategoriesA.html)

Answer (score -1):

This is the whole code:

```
 function initialize(){

  var deutschland = new google.maps.LatLng(51,9);

  var mapOptions = { zoom: 6,
                     center: deutschland,
                     streetViewControl: true,
                     scaleControl: true,
                     mapTypeControl: true,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),mapOptions);
  var beaches = [
 ['Bondi Beach', 51, 9, 1],
 ['Coogee Beach', 52, 9, 1],
 ['Cronulla Beach', 51, 8, 2],
 ['Manly Beach',51.5, 9, 2],
 ['Maroubra Beach',52.5, 10, 2]
  ];

 var markers = [];
 var i, newMarker;

 for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
   newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
    map: map,
    title: beaches[i][0]
  });

 newMarker.category = beaches[i][3];
 newMarker.setVisible(true);

 markers.push(newMarker);
 } 

 }

function displayMarkers(category) {
  var i;

 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   if (markers[i].category == category) {
     if (markers[i].getVisible()) {
          markers[i].setVisible(false); }

    else { markers[i].setVisible(true); } } }

  }
```

and:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Group 1" onclick="displayMarkers(1);"/>
   <input type="button" value="Show Group 2" onclick="displayMarkers(2);"/>
```

Comment: remove the var -keyword in this line:  `var markers = [];` to make the array global accessible

Comment: @user1953346 - your post here is not an answer.  Update your original question with all this code instead.

Comment: According to your advice I tried edit the text (menue: share/edit/ delete...) but it did't work?